# How to show in textview an entry from existing SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, textview

I am developing an android app in which there will be an activity with many buttons. In each of them I need to show a certain entry from an existing SQLite database. When you press a button it will show you a pop up window with a TextView, that will show the entry of the database that I said. Example: when you press button number 1 it will show you the entry with the ID number 1.

I have used SQLite Asset Helper to get my existing database, but I cant find out how to get my entries in their windows and I couldnt find anything online.

**My Mydatabase class for SQLite**

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;


public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase1.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}


}
```

**My Pop class for the pop up window**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

public class Pop extends Activity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.popwindow);

    DisplayMetrics dm= new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));
}}
```

**Please Help!**

Comment: Working with databases is covered in the documentation, plus books and courses on Android app development. They will show you how to use `getReadableDatabase()` and `rawQuery()` to retrieve data from your `MyDatabase` class. Setting text in a `TextView`, via `findViewById()` and `setText()`, is covered in countless places beyond those that I mentioned. So, given all of that, what **specifically** are you unable to find?

Answer (score 0):

You extract data from the database by running a query which is based upon SQL. The query returns a **Cursor**, which consists of rows of data.

You then extract the data from the **Cursor**, it's then just a matter of using the Text View's **`setText`** method.

---

Assuming a database has a single table named **mytable**, which has a single column named **mycolumn**. Then

The SQL could be `SELECT * FROM mytable` (this says to select all(**`*`**) columns from the table name mytable.), alternately the SQL could be `SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable` (in which case specific column has been named).

The SQL, as above could be run using the SQLiteDatabase `rawQuery` method e.g. (*where **db** is an SQLiteDatabase*)

`Cursor mycursor = db.rwaQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable",null);`

The preferred method though, is to use the SQLiteDatabase convenience method `query`.

e.g.

```
Cursor mycusror = db.query("mytable",String[]{"mycolumn"},null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

or alternately

```
Cursor mycusror = db.query("mytable",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

(this gets all columns i.e. 2nd parameter is null).

A Cursor can hold 0 or more rows and you can move through the cursor by using Cursor `move` methods e.g. `mycursor.moveToNext()`. When appropriately positioned, you then use one of the Cusror `get` methods e.g. `getString` to retrieve the data.

Assuming that your query could only obtain a single row (e.g. the WHERE clause includes _id=1) then you could for example use:-

```
if (mycursor.getCount() == 1) {
    String mytext = mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex("mycolumn"));
    mytextView.setText(mytext);
}
mycursor.close();
```

alternately the following would also work as the `move` methods will return false if the move cannot be made :-

```
while (mycursor.moveToNext) {
    String mytext = mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex("mycolumn"));
        mytextView.setText(mytext);
}
mycursor.close();
```